# jQuery create and open URL with ampersand

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I'm trying to build an URL in jquery and then open it. The problem is that the URL should contain an ampersand and I can't figure out how to do that

```
        var url = 'print?month=' +  jQuery('#month').val() + '&amp;year=' + jQuery('#year').val();
        var encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(url);
        window.open(encodedUrl);
```

Essentially, what I'd like the **URL** to be is: `print?month=1&year=2015`

Comment: Just do a `&`? This will not be HTML, it is in a variable in Javascript only.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, changing & a m p ; [without spaces] to & should work, if not you should probably do something like below:

```
var url = 'print?month=' +  encodeURIComponent(jQuery('#month').val()) + '&year=' + encodeURIComponent(jQuery('#year').val());
window.open(url);
```

Comment: If I change it to & I get the following error:
The reference to entity “year” must end with the ';' delimiter exception

Comment: did you try my second option?

Comment: btw where do you get this ; delimiter exception? If in server it would give us an idea on what the server is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Fully working plnkr is at:http://plnkr.co/edit/70h1E8SJDXMhtMJPnKMp?p=preview

Just enable popups on your browser for plnkr if you dont see the popup yet.

Basically just create a string with concatenating `&` charecters, its just a string, you dont need to URIEncode it, then do a window.open of the string. That should do it.